# Setting WM_KEYDOWN lParam parameters

Tags: c#, winapi

```
public class sendKeys {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr, lParam);

    public static void sendKeystroke(ushort k)
        {
            const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
            const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x018;
            const uint SC_CLOSE = 0x053;

            IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "processname");

            IntPtr result3 = SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)k), (IntPtr)0);
        }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
I can read in the page above, that the lParam argument should contain all the parameters I want to send, in bits. If, for example, I wanted to send a "0x2D" value for the ScanCode,  how should I do it?

Comment: As you are not really sending pointers, but actual int values, you could also use: 
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
In this case you won't need to cast to IntPtr.

Comment: This doesn't look like the right solution to your problem, but we cannot tell you the right solution because you did not tell us the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSDN page tells you what bits of `lParam` to use for each of the parameters. All you need to do is some bit shifting to assemble `lParam`:

```
uint repeatCount = 0;
uint scanCode = 0x2D;
uint extended = 0;
uint context = 0;
uint previousState = 0;
uint transition = 0;

// combine the parameters above according to the bit
// fields described in the MSDN page for WM_KEYDOWN

uint lParam = repeatCount
    | (scanCode << 16)
    | (extended << 24)
    | (context << 29)
    | (previousState << 30)
    | (transition << 31);
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the WM_KEYDOWN message, but not for the [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, where I should set both previousState and transition to 1, as a ArithmeticOverflowException is thrown

Comment: @Phoenìx I can't reproduce this (it works fine for me and no exception is thrown). Are you using the *exact* code I posted above (just with `previousState` and `transition` set to `1`)?

Comment: @dvnrss Yes, I'm using the same code you posted. By the way, the problems seems to be solved if I replace IntPtr with Int32 in the function declaration as csgero suggested, but why?

Comment: @Phoenìx It really should be `IntPtr` for 64-bit compatibility; using `UInt32` will fail if you link to the 64-bit Windows API. `IntPtr` is either 32 bits or 64 bits to match the target environment (and so is `LPARAM` used in the `SendMessage()` definition). As for your overflow error, I really have no idea; the code I posted works just fine for me.

Comment: Necro helper message for future travelers. You can use this code and it works, but you need to do an unchecked conversion from 'uint' to 'int' before IntPtr. You definitely should use IntPtr or learn to use it, so much is 64 bit now.  So do: var iplParam  = unchecked((IntPtr)(int)lParam); then use the ipLParam in the Win API call.

Comment: Pt 2: unchecked uint to int allows the high bit to be kept and being int stops a lot of issues putting a uint into an IntPtr. Technically the WPARAM is unsigned and UIntPtr and LPARAM is signed and IntPtr. But no one does that. So these unchecked conversions are a good to learn and useful. Setting transition to 1 sets the highest bit, and causes the overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Here's more complete example using TypeIA's answer to help those with the overflow issue.  I'm adding this because his answer is one of the most correct and down into the necessary nitty-gritty of any I've seen on SO to actually make this work.

---

TypeIA's and Fehniix's with conversions:

The MSDN page tells you what bits of `lParam` to use for each of the parameters. All you need to do is some bit shifting to assemble `lParam`:

```
const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x018;
const uint SC_CLOSE = 0x053;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

uint repeatCount = 0;
uint scanCode = k;
uint extended = 0;
uint context = 0;
uint previousState = 0;
uint transition = 0;

// combine the parameters above according to the bit
// fields described in the MSDN page for WM_KEYDOWN

uint lParamDown = repeatCount
    | (scanCode << 16)
    | (extended << 24)
    | (context << 29)
    | (previousState << 30)
    | (transition << 31);

previousState = 1;
transition = 1;

uint lParamUp = repeatCount
    | (scanCode << 16)
    | (extended << 24)
    | (context << 29)
    | (previousState << 30)
    | (transition << 31);

var ipKey = (IntPtr)(int)k;
var ipLParamDown = unchecked((IntPtr)(int)lParamDown);
var ipLParamUp = unchecked((IntPtr)(int)lParamUp);

IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "processname");

IntPtr result3 = SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_KEYDOWN, ipKey, ipLParamDown);
IntPtr result4 = SendMessage(WindowToFind, WM_KEYUP, ipKey, ipLParamUp);
```